# cgi script is sending form data multiple times, once per refresh

Tags: javascript, python, forms, cgi

I'm trying to write my own webmail application using python cgi with smtplib and imaplib.  When I hit the send button on the "send" form the email is sent, however, for every refresh after that the message is sent again.  The page (cgi script) is refreshed automatically every two minutes via javascript:

```
  <script language="javascript">

    window.setInterval('refresh()', 180000);

    function refresh() 
    {
      // this checks to see which tab is selected, page is refreshed only if compose tab is not selected
      elList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for (i = 0; i < elList.length; i++)
      { 
        if (elList[i].className === 'tab active') 
        {
          var activeTab = elList[i].innerHTML;
        }
      }

      if (activeTab.indexOf("Unread") >= 0)
      {
         window.location.reload(true);
      }

    } 
  </script>
```

I can't really tell whether the form data is sent multiple times or just read multiple times.  However, I see no reason why the form should be submitted again on refresh so I have to believe that it is just being read multiple times.  Here are the components, which enable the reading of the form data:

```
# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if form.keys() != []:
  for x in form.keys():
    if x == 'send':
      send_email()
```

I tried to reset the form using javascript in the page head tag, but this did not work:

```
<script language="javascript">
  Form.reset('send');  // reset send form so email is not sent again
</script>
```

For completeness, here is the form definition:

```
  <form name="send" action="/cgi-bin/myemail.py" method="post" >
  <table id="example" class="compose" >
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="To:" style="height: 1.95em; width: 4em"></td><td><input type="text" name="send_to" size="90"></td><td><input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND" style="height: 1.95em; width: 12em"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Cc:" style="height: 1.95em; width: 4em"></td><td><input type="text" name="send_cc" size="90"></td> <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="SAVE" style="height: 1.95em; width: 12em"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Bcc:" style="height: 1.95em; width: 4em"></td><td><input type="text" name="send_bcc" size="90"></td> <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="DELETE" style="height: 1.95em; width: 12em"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Subj:" style="height: 1.95em; width: 4em"></td><td><input type="text" name="send_subj" size="90"></td> <td><input type="submit" name="send" size="200" value="ATTACH" style="height: 1.95em; width: 12em"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <!-- <td colspan="3"> <div id="result" class="body" style="background-color:#000000"></div></td> -->
        <textarea name="send_body" cols="118" rows="23"> </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

How can I keep this form data from being read multiple times?  Thanks.

Comment: are you using POST or GET to send the form data?

Comment: @Lee Taylor, Correct me if I'm wrong but that is defined in the form tag as method="post"

Comment: Damn, yes correct. I clearly can't read today!